# Loop is not waiting for query to be executed in node js

Tags: node.js, async-await

**I am using node-querybuilder module for executing queries. I need to loop query in loop.
dbConfig.getDB() returns connection and why loop is not waiting for the query to execute**

**firstHalf and secondHalf always A and A..loop is not waiting for query to be executed.
I am very new to node-querybuilder module.using async and await doesn't make any difference**

````
        dbConfig.getDB().query(`SELECT id, full_name, email,mobile from frms WHERE status = ? AND email IS NOT NULL`, ['1'], async (err, response) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
            else if (response && response.length > 0) {
                var curr = new Date;
                var firstday = new Date(curr.setDate(curr.getDate() - curr.getDay() - 6));
                var weekArr = [firstday];
                for (let j = 1; j < 6; j++) {
                    var nextday = new Date(curr.setDate(firstday.getDate() + j));
                    weekArr.push(nextday);
                }
                // console.log(weekArr);
                let dayWiseAttendanceArr = [];
                for (let i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                    let frmWiseObj = {};
                    frmWiseObj.basic_details = { "id": response[i].id, "name": response[i].full_name, "email": response[i].email, "mobile": response[i].mobile };
                    frmWiseObj.attendance_details = [];
                    for (let k = 0; k < weekArr.length; k++) {
                        let inDate = weekArr[k].toISOString().split('T')[0];
                        let dateWiseObj = {};
                        dateWiseObj.date = inDate;
                        let firstHalf = "A";
                        let secondHalf = "A";
                        let query = `SELECT DATE_FORMAT(in_date,'%Y-%m-%d') as date,ifnull(in_date,'') as punch_in,ifnull(out_date,'') as punch_out  FROM punching_detail where DATE_FORMAT(in_date,'%Y-%m-%d') = '${inDate}' and punching_detail.frm_id='${response[i].id}'`;
                        dbConfig.getDB().query(query, async (punch_err, punch_response) => {
                            if (punch_err) {
                                console.log(punch_err);
                            } else if (punch_response && punch_response.length > 0) {
                                let punch_in = punch_response[0].punch_in;
                                let punch_out = punch_response[0].punch_out;
                                if (punch_in <= (inDate + " 10:40:00") && punch_out >= (inDate + " 19:00:00")) {
                                    firstHalf = "P";
                                    secondHalf = "P";
                                } else if (punch_in <= (inDate + " 10:40:00") && punch_out <= (inDate + " 19:00:00") && punch_out >= (inDate + " 14:30:00")) {
                                    firstHalf = "P";
                                    secondHalf = "A";
                                } else if (punch_in >= (inDate + " 10:40:00") && punch_in <= (inDate + " 14:30:00") && punch_out >= (inDate + " 19:00:00")) {
                                    firstHalf = "A";
                                    secondHalf = "P";
                                } else if (punch_in >= (inDate + " 10:40:00") && punch_in <= (inDate + " 14:30:00") && punch_in <= (inDate + " 19:00:00")) {
                                    var hours = Math.abs(punch_out - punch_in) / (60 * 60 * 1000);
                                    if (hours >= 4.5) {
                                        firstHalf = "P";
                                        secondHalf = "A";
                                    } else {
                                        firstHalf = "P";
                                        secondHalf = "P";
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    firstHalf = "A";
                                    secondHalf = "A";
                                }
                            } else {
                                let query = `SELECT leave_type,start_day, end_day,DATE_FORMAT(start_date,'%Y-%m-%d') as date,DATE_FORMAT(end_date,'%Y-%m-%d') as end_date FROM leave_mgt where (DATE_FORMAT(end_date,'%Y-%m-%d') <= '${inDate}}' AND DATE_FORMAT(start_date,'%Y-%m-%d') <= '${inDate}}') and frm_id='${response[i].id}' and status = '1'`;
                                await dbConfig.getDB().query(query, async (leave_err, leave_response) => {
                                    if (leave_err) {
                                        console.log(leave_err);
                                    } else if (leave_response && leave_response.length > 0) {
                                        const element = leave_response[0];
                                        if (element.end_date != '0000-00-00') {
                                            if (element.start_date == inDate) {

                                                if (element.start_day == 2) {
                                                    firstHalf = 'L';
                                                    secondHalf = 'L';
                                                } else if (element.start_day == 0) {
                                                    firstHalf = 'L';
                                                } else if (element.start_day == 1) {
                                                    secondHalf = 'L';
                                                }
                                            } else if (element.end_date == inDate) {
                                                if (element.end_day == 2) {
                                                    firstHalf = 'L';
                                                    secondHalf = 'L';
                                                } else if (element.end_day == 0) {
                                                    firstHalf = 'L';
                                                } else if (element.end_day == 1) {
                                                    secondHalf = 'L';
                                                }

                                            } else {
                                                firstHalf = 'L';
                                                secondHalf = 'L';
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                            dateWiseObj.first_half = firstHalf;
                            dateWiseObj.second_half = secondHalf;
                            frmWiseObj.attendance_details.push(dateWiseObj);
                        });
                    }
                   
                    dayWiseAttendanceArr.push(frmWiseObj);
                }
             
            }
            else {
                console.log("No Active frms found");
            }
        });
    }```
````

Answer (score 0):

Am not familiar with `node-querybuilder` but on this line:

```
await dbConfig.getDB().query(query, async (leave_err, leave_response) => {/* some code */ });
```

since the `query` method takes in a callback, it probably does not return a promise (you could confirm this by looking at the documentation/source code). This means using `await` here will not make your code wait for `query` to complete (since `await` has to be followed by a promise for it to have any effect).

If the library you're using doesn't use promises, maybe try promisifying the `query` method, so that you can `await` it. Promisifying can be done using something built-in like `util/promisify` or manually by creating a wrapper function (something like below):

```
function queryAsPromise(sql, parameters) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    dbConfig.getDB().query(sql, parameters, (err, response) => {
      if (err) {
        return reject(err);
      }
      resolve(response);
    });
  });
}
```

You can then `await` whatever `queryAsPromise` resolves to, like below:

```
async function main() {
  const response = await queryAsPromise(
    `SELECT id, full_name, email,mobile from frms WHERE status = ? AND email IS NOT NULL`,
    [1]
  );
  // Rest of your code...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use a promisified helper function to execute your queries and return the result?

```
// DB setup
const dbConfig = {
    host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
    user: process.env.DATABASE_USER,
    password: process.env.DATABASE_PASS,
    database: process.env.DATABASE_NAME,
    port: process.env.DATABASE_PORT,
}

// Connection handler
const handleConnection = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const client = mysql.createConnection(dbConfig);  // Recreate the connection, since the old one cannot be reused.
        client.connect(function onConnect(err) {   // The server is either down
            if (err) {                                  // or restarting (takes a while sometimes).
                console.log('error when connecting to db:', err);
                setTimeout(handleConnection, 10000);    // We introduce a delay before attempting to reconnect,
                return;
            }                                       // to avoid a hot loop, and to allow our node script to
            console.log('Database connected.');
            resolve(client);
        });
        // process asynchronous requests in the meantime.
        // If you're also serving http, display a 503 error.
        client.on('error', function onError(err) {
            console.log('db error', err);
            if (err.code == 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST') {   // Connection to the MySQL server is usually
                handleConnection();                         // lost due to either server restart, or a
            } else {                                        // connnection idle timeout (the wait_timeout
                reject(err);                                  // server variable configures this)
            }
        });
    })
}

// Query handler
export.mySql = (query, values = null) => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {

        try {
            const client = await handleConnection();
            let db = client;
            db.query(query, values, (err, result, fields) => {
                if (!err) {
                    resolve(result);
                    client.end();
                    console.log('Query executed');
                    return;
                }
                client.end();
                throw err;
            });
        } catch (error) {
            reject(err);
        }

    });
}
```

So whenever you call the `mySql` function; it connects to DB, executes the query, and returns the result.

Usage:

```
const { mySql } = require('./db.js');

const result = await mySql(`SELECT id, full_name, email,mobile from frms WHERE status = ? AND email IS NOT NULL`, ['1']);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: for some reason i am getting an error: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'`