# Sharing a mysql connection between client and server js files in node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, socket.io

I've seen sort of similar questions on here, but none exactly like this, so I hope I'm not repeating something that's already been asked.

I'm pretty new to node.js & socket.io so please bear with me, and the project I'm trying to build a multi-chat room app.

I'm stuck at the step where I am trying to separate my code into "modules". My project directory structure is as follows.

[image: Project Directory Structure]

My index.js initiates the express server and sets up the basic socket.io connection. As I understand it, this starting point index.js file is "server-side" js.

**Index.js**

```
const path = require('path')
const http = require('http')
const express = require('express')
const socketio = require('socket.io')
const { generatemsg } = require('./utils/messages')
const { addUser, removeUser, getUser, getUserInRoom } = require('./utils/users')
const pool = require('./utils/dbconfig');
const db = require('../public/js/database');

const app = express()
const server = http.createServer(app)
const io = socketio(server)
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000

const publicdir = path.join(__dirname, '../public')

app.use(express.static(publicdir))

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    console.log("new connection from socket.io")

    socket.on("join", ({ username, room }, cb) => {

        const { error, user } = addUser({ id: socket.id, username, room })

        if (error) {
            return cb(error)
        }
        
        socket.join(user.room)

        //generate random color
        const colorsArray = ["red", "green", "lime", "purple", "blue"]
        var arrayPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * colorsArray.length)
        var colorTmp = colorsArray[arrayPos]

        //Add New User to DB
        var userTmp = user.username
        var roomTmp = user.room
        
        db.addCurrentUserToDB(userTmp, roomTmp, colorTmp)

        io.to(user.room).emit("roomData", {
            room: user.room,
            users: getUserInRoom(user.room)
        })
        
        cb()
    })

    socket.on("sendMessage", (msg, cb) => {
        const user = getUser(socket.id)
        io.to(user.room).emit("message", generatemsg(user.username, msg))
        cb()
    })

    socket.on("disconnect", () => {
        const user = removeUser(socket.id)
        console.log(user)
        if (user) {
            io.to(user.room).emit("message", generatemsg(`${user.username} left.`))

            io.to(user.room).emit("roomData", {
                room: user.room,
                users: getUserInRoom(user.room)
            })
        }
    })
})


server.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log("server is up at port: " + PORT)
})
```

So my understanding of when things transfer from server-side.js to client-side.js start to get squirrely for me here. Index.js is server-side.js because I'm able to use some variable = require('some module');

Then in my utils directory is my database config file. In order to share a mysql connection, I believe I need to create a pool connection, which is what i'm attempting to do here.

**dbconfig.js**

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

const pool  = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit : 100,
    host: "xxxx",
    port: 3306,
    user: "xxxx",
    password: "xxxx",
    database: 'xxxx',
    multipleStatements: true
});

pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
    if (err) throw err; // not connected!
    
    console.log('Connected from dbconfig.js');
});

module.exports.pool = pool;
```

For reasons I don't fully understand, the files in the utils folder still seem to be server-side js which is why I'm able to include them into the index.js file and make use of a function in the database.js file (client-side).

In the public/js folder I am storing all of my database functions that I will call at random times throughout the app.

**Database.js** (shortened for brevity)

```
    //Add New User
    function addCurrentUserToDB(userTmp, roomTmp, colorTmp) {
    var sql = 'INSERT INTO pzs_info (username, roomname, usercolor) VALUES (?, ?, ?)';

    pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
        if (err) throw err; // not connected!
      
        // Use the connection
        connection.query(sql, [userTmp, roomTmp, colorTmp], (err, result, fields) => {
            if (err) throw err;
        
            console.log('Added user' + userTmp); //result.changedRows
            connection.release();
        });
    });
}
```

The database.js file now seems to "client-side" js and as such, can't seem to access the mysql connection (as it's stored in what I'm guessing is a server-side.js file), even though I exported it in the dbconfig.js file.

depending on how I vary the above code, I will get errors ranging from pool is not a function or pool is undefined, and in the latest version I've been experimenting with like this:

**Database.js**

```
const dbstuff = require('../../src/utils/dbconfig');

//Add New User
function addCurrentUserToDB(userTmp, roomTmp, colorTmp) {
    var sql = 'INSERT INTO pzs_info (username, roomname, usercolor) VALUES (?, ?, ?)';

    dbstuff.pool.query(sql, [userTmp, roomTmp, colorTmp], function (error, results, fields) {
        if (error) throw error;
        console.log('Added user' + userTmp); //result.changedRows
    });
}
```

I'm guessing this is because at this point, the database.js file is now client-side.js and can't use the require function.

BUT what is interesting is that even though it gives me the can't use the require error message from the database.js file in console.log, it DOES still actually write the username / room / color to the database. Go figure.

My guess is that there is some basic logic of how node shares functions between client/server side that is totally escaping me.

**UPDATE:**
Well I've made small amounts of progress, thanks to a suggestion here to add in the esm module, which is allowing me to mix/match require with import statements.

So I'm now able to pull in the connection in the database.js file from the dbconfig.js file (dbconfig is server, database is client) so that's good.

However I'm stuck on trying to get the database.js file into the chat.js file (which are both client side).

I've tried adding an import statement to the top of the chat.js file

```
import { updateUserList } from './database.js';
```

However this produces a SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module error.

if I also add the type="module" to my chat.html file like so:

```
<script src="/js/chat.js" type="module"></script>
```

Then I get several different errors. a 404 error on the chat.js file, a file was blocked because of disallowed mime type error, etc etc.

Soo... I'm spinning my wheels again. Not sure why I can't just include the database.js file in my chat.html file and call it a day.

Please advise.

Comment: Tip: One thing that can help is using ES6 `import` instead of the Node-specific `require`.

Comment: I gave a modular MySQL connection and query handler function in an answer. That might fix your problem I believe. https://stackoverflow.com/a/67722081/13772090

Comment: @MuratColyaran, Your other answer goes a bit over my head with the whole promises thing, but I'm wondering if I try to use this part of it    const { mySql } = require('./db.js');  in my database.js file, I'm just going to run into the same issue (require isn't understood).

Comment: @Nick No, it won't work like that. If you copy that answer to a file as it is. You can run any  query you want by calling that function wherever you want. It works very clean. Of course, you have to give the environment variables right.

Comment: @MuratColyaran Ok, I think I'm still missing something. , I can take your previous answer and put it into a file (let's call it db.js) and it would be server side js (possibly) however your saying I could access it from anywhere using your usage method. 

I'm still having a disconnect, because I don't see how I can call it from client side js files, as the require function won't work in client side js.

I am certainly willing to give it a try though. :)

Comment: @Nick You need to have `db.js` for both sides. But the important thing is you need to use the same DB configuration for both. (host, password dbname etc.). After you made the db connection. Just call the function and execute the query. The part I think will do your best. Since this function does not keep the connection active, you can run queries on both server and customer sides as you wish.

Comment: @MuratColyaran  so the db.js file would feed as many client side js files as necessary. So for example db.js has the connection info in it and then when js-1 or js-2 wants to use the connection, they would call the connection located in the db.js file.  Do I understand that correctly? :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233027/discussion-between-murat-colyaran-and-nick).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Murat's link to a mysql connection / response was definitely helpful and sent me down the right path. This is the link to the other question.

stackoverflow.com/a/67722081/13772090

However, ultimately I ended up going the Pub / Sub route using a 3rd party service, and that's working a lot better for me than trying to build out my own infrastructure. I went with Ably if anyone's curious.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

In **Database.js** file, dbstuff is your pool variable. Use **dbstuff.query** instead of dbstuff.pool.query.

Comment: I tried that, and I just got a dbstuff.query is not a function error. =/
I think it's because I can't use require in client-side js.